# Help with a minimization question

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Let 
$$z_1 = 3x_1 + x_2 + x_3$$

$$z_2 = 2x_1 + 5x_2 + 2x_3$$

$$z_3 = x_2 + 7x_3$$

There exists a variable $w$ defined as:
$$w = \min(z_1, z_2, z_3)$$

Also, the $x$-variables are subject to the following restrictions:

$$x_1 + 0.35x_2 + .5x_3 \leq 100$$

$$3x_1 + 2x_2 + 0.35x_3 \leq 360$$

$$2x_1 + 5x_2 + 35x_3 \geq 500$$

$x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ are real and positive

(i.e. Find the values that minimize the maximum of the three linear expressions ($z_1$, $z_2$, and $z_3$) which are subject to three additional restrictions)

a) Transform the problem stated above into one of linear programming. (Hint: We are looking for the smallest w that is greater than $z_1$, $z_2$, and $z_3$)

I am really lost. Can someone please explain this problem to me?
I am sorry that I don't know how the format for the subscripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this looks like a homework question, I can give you hints, and if you still don't get it, I can give more hints...

Based on the first 3 equations:
$${z_1 = 3x_1 + x_2 + x_3}$$
$${z_2 = 2x_1 + 5x_2 + 2x_3}$$
$${z_3 = x_2 + 7x_3}$$
Can you rewrite the equations to get $x_i$ in terms of $z_i$? Something along the lines of
$${x_1 = az_1 + bz_2 + cz_3}$$
where $a, b, c$ are real constants for all three $x_i$.
Once you do that, you can just substitute $x_i$ in terms of $z_i$ in the inequalities. Something along the lines of:
$${k_1z_1 + k_2z_2 + k_3z_3 \leq 100}$$
Where $k_1,k_2,k_3$ are real constants.

Does that look similar to a linear programming question where you are minimizing $w$?

Comment: Thank you! I already put xi in terms of zi and the restrictions in terms of zi. However, I still don't get how will the objective function look like.

Comment: Is w supposed to be z1 + z2 + z3?

Comment: @Lollipop no, according to the question you need to minimise max($z_1,z_2,z_3$)... then find the smallest integer greater than that... Do you know how to do that?

Comment: No, I am lost. So do I have to maximise z1, z2 and z3 separately and then find the smallest integer greater than the largest of the z's? But how would the formula for w look like?  I am sorry but I haven't seen anything like this on class. This is just a study question.

Comment: Yep, that is one way to do it... https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-053-optimization-methods-in-management-science-spring-2013/tutorials/MIT15_053S13_tut04.pdf should have a better tutorial then I can give you over stack...

Comment: Thank you so much!!